# Challenging Taylor expansion involving a summation of logarithms

Tags: summation, logarithms, taylor-expansion

I am a researcher and encountered the following challenging function in my work:

$$f(S)=\sum_{k=1}^{S-1}(\ln (S)-\ln (k))^2 \bigg [ \frac{1}{(S-k)^2}+\frac{1}{(S+k)^2} \bigg ]$$

And I am only interested in the first term of the Taylor expansion of this function when $S->+\infty$. Matlab simulations give me that it is equivalent to:

$$\frac{a}{S}$$

In other words, simply a positive scalar divided by the parameter $S$.

Do you have any idea how to compute this term?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome. Please type up your expressions using MathJax or at the very least embed your images into the post so they are visible.

Comment: I have done this for you now (but you could consider typing up the other expression)

Comment: Ignoring issues of convergence for small $\frac{k}{S}$, $Sf(S)$ has the form of a Riemann sum. This suggests $a = \int_0^1 \log(x)^2\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} + \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}\right)dx \sim 4.9348022$ (according to [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N%5BIntegral%5BLog%5Bx%5D%5E2*%281%2F%281-x%29%5E2+%2B+1%2F%281%2Bx%29%5E2%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%5D%2C50%5D)). 
For comparison, $Sf(S) \sim 4.934556$ at $S = 10^6$, so it is possible your $a$ is given by above integral.

Comment: @achillehui. And this number is .... simple.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici if you didn't point that out, I won't recognize it matches $\frac{\pi^2}{2}$ numerically.

Comment: @achillehui. Correct (for sure). You even can compute the antiderivative and the number is the limit of $$-\frac{2 \left(\left(x^2-1\right) \text{Li}_2(-x)-\left(x^2-1\right)
   \text{Li}_2(x)+\log (x) \left(2 \left(x^2-1\right) \tanh ^{-1}(x)+x \log
   (x)\right)\right)}{x^2-1}$$ when $x\to 1$. $\pi$ is everywhere !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(S)=\frac{1}{S}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{1}{S}\sum_{k=1}^{S-1}\log^2\left(\frac{k}{S}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{k}{S}\right)^2}+\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{k}{S}\right)^2}\right)}_{\text{Riemann sum}}$$

And the Riemann sum converges to

$$ a=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^2(x)}{(1-x)^2}\,dx + \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^2(x)}{(1+x)^2}\,dx. $$
Considering that $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n\geq 0}(n+1) x^n$ and $\int_{0}^{1}x^n\log^2(x)\,dx=\frac{2}{(n+1)^3}$ we have

$$ a = 4\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(2n+1)}{(2n+1)^3}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi^2}{2}}. $$

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate the first term- when k'= 1?  That should be easy:
$(ln(S)- ln(1))^2\left[\frac{1}{(S-1)^2}- \frac{1}{(S+1)^2}\right]$
$= (ln(S)- 0)^2\left[\frac{(S+1)^2- (S-1)^2}{(S+1)^2(S-1)^2}\right]$
$= (ln(S))^2\left[\frac{S^2+ 2S+ 1- S^2+ 2S- 1}{(S+1)^2(S-1)^2}\right]$
$= \frac{4ln(S)S}{(S+1)^2(S-1)^2}$

You can multiply out the denominator if you like but that is not really useful.

Comment: I may be stupid but I do not see how this could give the value of $a$. Moreover, inside brackets, it is a $+$ and not a $-$.