# More challenging Taylor expansion involving a summation of logarithms

Tags: summation, logarithms, taylor-expansion, riemann-sum

I am a researcher and encountered the following challenging function in my work:

$$f(S)=\sum_{k=1}^{S-1} \bigg[ \frac{1}{k^2(2k-1)^2(2k+1)^2} \bigg] 
\bigg( (2k-1)[-\ln(1+4S)+\ln(-1+4(S-k))] + (2k+1)[+\ln(-1+4S)-\ln(1+4(S-k))] \bigg)^2 $$

And I am only interested in the first term of the Taylor expansion of this function when $S\rightarrow+\infty$. Matlab simulations give me that it is equivalent to:

$$\frac{a}{S^4}\  , \quad a>0$$

In other words, simply a positive scalar divided by the parameter $S^4$.

Do you have any idea how to compute this term?

PS: I have tried to manipulate the expression such as to obtain a Riemann sum like in the previous post ([Challenging Taylor expansion involving a summation of logarithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4237342/challenging-taylor-expansion-involving-a-summation-of-logarithms/4237390#4237390)), but this seems more complicated to obtain.

Thank you so much.

Comment: hint: write $\ln(a+bS)=\ln(S)+\ln(b+{a \over S})$

Comment: I did that and it gives:
$$ +\ln\Bigg( 1-2\Bigg(\frac{2\frac{k}{S}+\frac{1}{S}}{4+\frac{1}{S}}\Bigg) \Bigg)$$
for the first logs, and,
$$ -\ln\Bigg( 1-2\Bigg(\frac{2\frac{k}{S}-\frac{1}{S}}{-4+\frac{1}{S}}\Bigg) \Bigg)$$
for the last logs.
So that I get an expression with $\frac{k}{S}$ but then I don't see how to translate it into the Riemann sum, because of the fractions $\frac{1}{S}$, which I can't get ride of.

Comment: $1\over S$ is small, so you may expand.

Comment: If I understood what you mean, the respective expansion within the logs are:
$$ +\ln\Bigg( 1-\frac{k}{S} - \frac{1}{2S} + \frac{2}{S}\frac{k}{S} \Bigg) $$
And
$$ -\ln\Bigg( 1-\frac{k}{S} + \frac{1}{2S} - \frac{2}{S}\frac{k}{S} \Bigg) $$
But I will always end up with the fractions $\frac{1}{S}$ which prevent to convert it to a Riemann sum, isn't it?

Comment: $a$ would be a rather small number. Computed for $S=10^6$, it is $0.1013211836$ which is not recognized by ISC.